# Writing argument results to a text file

Tags: file, batch-file, vbscript, arguments

I am making an Invoice that will use a batch file to add the totals.
I have it at the end of the project but I can not get the vb script to write the arguments to a txt file.
My borrowed script:

```
@echo off
cscript.exe //nologo //H:cscript>nul
set /P score=Please enter the first number %=%

set /P score2=Please enter the first number %=%
for /f %%i in ('domath.vbs //nologo "(%score%*%score2%)"') do set answer=%%i 
@echo answer=%answer%
cscript.exe //nologo //H:wscript>nul
@echo %answer%>12345.txt
```

Here is the 'domath.vbs  script that does the math:

```
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
wscript.echo eval(objArgs(0))
```

I have tried several attempts but I just do not know enough to get the output to go to text.
Can anyone tell me I think I am at the point that I am missing something very simple.
Everything that I try it just will echo to a popup but never writes to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run your `vbs` with `cscript` to output the answer in the console :

```
@echo off

set /P "score=Please enter the first number = "
set /P "score2=Please enter the second number = "

for /f %%i in ('cscript //nologo domath.vbs "(%score%*%score2%)"') do set "answer=%%i" 
echo answer=%answer%
echo %answer%>12345.txt
pause
```

Comment: Now it just disappears and no 12345.txt

Comment: Test my edit (with `pause` at the end) and check if you have the answer in the CMD

Comment: Please put the question as answered !